# Removing Duplicate Values within Group By

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL-Server 2012 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

As a preface, I cannot use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col)` as the `OVER()` method is not supported by the Visual Studio Version I am using.  I am not in a place, unfortunately, where I can get new software.

I have a group of department and job IDs such that:

```
SELECT 
   Department, 
   Job_ID
FROM 
   Table1 
JOIN Table2 on 
Table1.id = Table2.id


Department       Job_ID
__________________________

 Marketing         J3
 Engineering       J1
 Marketing         J2
 Recruiting        J2
 Marketing         J8
 Administration    J3
 Recruiting        J1
 Administration    J5
 Administration    J1
```

I am trying to group by Job_ID, show the distinct Departments associated with each Job_ID, and only include groups that have more than 2 departments. The end results would be:

```
Department       Job_ID
__________________________

 Administration    J1
 Recruiting        J1
 Engineering       J1
 Marketing         J2
 Recruiting        J2
 Marketing         J3
 Administration    J3
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT Job_ID, count(distinct(Department)) as Dept_CountD
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id
GROUP BY Job_ID
HAVING count(distinct(Department)) >1
```

This works, however, it does not group the departments along with each ID.  I also know (and have tested) that I cannot insert Department into the Group By statement, as that would return distinct department counts only equal to 1!

I have tried building the above statement into a CTE and inner joining on the Job_ID so I only have Job_IDs that have more than 2 distinct departments associated with them, however, I end up with duplicate Departments in the grouping from the join.

I'm thinking perhaps joining to a sub query or doing a semi join?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY )" as the "OVER()" method is not supported by the Visual Studio Version I am using"?  It is the version of SQL Server that determines what scripts work and which don't and SQL Server 2012 supports the `OVER` clause.

Comment: What is a "semi join?"

Comment: Expected output is already written.  It is the second block of data after the "The end results would be:"

Comment: Semi join example is: SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT t1_id FROM table2 WHERE date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."  I have done a bit of trouble shooting on this already.  Although most SQL Server 2012 doesn't really "support" OVER(), it will normally run a query with it anyway.  For whatever reason, I am one of the smaller group of people where OVER() will not work.  A lot of folks seem to have some issue with it, but are able to get it working.  Some (like me), unfortunately it will not work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
   Department, 
   Job_ID
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
WHERE Job_ID IN (SELECT Job_ID
                 FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id
                 GROUP BY Job_ID
                 HAVING count(distinct(Department)) >1)
```

Comment: Yes @Tim, we can alternatively do it using a `JOIN`.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for (and was formulating in my head after I gave up on the problem last night after 2 hours of banging my head on the keyboard).  I have generally been spoiled by CTEs and have weak intuition with subqueries.

Comment: @Holmes Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT() Over()` window aggregate

```
select * from 
(
select count(1)over(partition by Job_ID) as cnt,*
From <<join>>
) A
Where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: ( I am only guessing which table has the Departments and which has the Jobs cause you did not provide schema.

```
  SELECT Job_ID, count(*) Dept_CountD
  FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b on a.id=b.id
  where (Select count(*) from table1
         Where JobId = a.JobId) > 1
```